# opendir() in FUSE

Tags: fuse

In the implemention of `xxx_readdir()`  in **FUSE**, I use the codes below:

```
static int hello_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
                         off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *de;

    (void) offset;
    (void) fi;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if (dp == NULL)
        return -errno;

    while ((de = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        struct stat st;
        memset(&st, 0, sizeof(st));
        st.st_ino = de->d_ino;
        st.st_mode = de->d_type << 12;
        if (filler(buf, de->d_name, &st, 0))
            break;
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, compile and execute on a foler:

```
./hello /tmp/hello/
```

When I use `ls /tmp/hello/` command, the results are as below:

```
bin   dev  home  lib64       media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
```

However, I have not created any file or directory in `/tmp/hello/`. So, why are these direcoties reside on it when I use the `ls` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call:

```
dp = opendir(path);
```

to begin your `readdir` implementation. When you call that `path` is *relative* to the root of your filesystem, not an absolute path on your system.

So in /tmp/hello/ the value of `path` will be '/' because it doesn't make sense for filesystems to need to know the details of where they're mounted. There's a deliberate abstraction there that makes it such that each filesystem is only concerned with things it stores.

Comment: Then, what if I want `readdir` could display the files and directories that really in the `/tmp/hello` folder? What shall I do?

Comment: @injoy - that's tricky because you have to make sure that your `opendir` call doesn't get passed back to fuse. A better design would be to have the mount point and the directory you show as different directories, i.e. `/tmp/hello.real` which your FUSE program mounts in `/tmp/hello`. You can pass the 'real' path to your program at run time and then just record that.

Comment: thanks and btw, could you recommend some good and simple (more complex than `hello.c`) FS implementation using FUSE?

Comment: @injoy - there's a list on the FUSE site. I'd suggest [localfs](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems#localfs) since it sounds similar to what you're trying to do. The network ones usually make good examples, I think I read httpfs last time I was looking for one.